# Passing array of objects to method

Tags: java

When we pass an Object[] to method, do we actually copy included objects or we just pass the array of references to those objects?

Comment: Java _never_ copies objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just passing a reference to the array. Neither the array nor any objects in it are copied.